# Aligning several forest trees in centered way

Tags: vertical-alignment, linguistics, forest

I want to align three trees in the way shown in the following figure:

[image]

What I have now is the following code:

```
\documentclass{minimal}   

\usepackage{forest}

\forestset{
tag/.style={for tree={parent anchor=south, child anchor=north,align=center,base=top},where
  n children=0{}{}}
}


\begin{document}


\hfill
\begin{forest}
tag
[NP
        [John]]
\end{forest}
\hfill
\begin{forest}
tag
[S
        [NP$\downarrow$]
        [VP
                [V
                        [laughs]]]]
\end{forest}
\hfill
\begin{forest}
tag
[VP
        [ADV
                [always]]
        [VP*]]
\end{forest}
\hfill\mbox{}

\end{document}
```

I know of the `baseline` attribute, but this would not do real centering. Before using `forest` I just used tables and this got the alignment right automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can think of two ways of accompishing this without external help.  Both use the fact that `tikz`/`pgf` keeps track of the picture's bounds in a special node called `current bounding box`.

1. Use `tikz`'s `baseline` option, which must be given as an argument to `tikzpicture` environment.  This can be achieved by changing `forest`'s option `begin draw` (at any node, but probably in the preamble)
2. Use `pgf`'s `\pgfsetbaselinepointlater`, which can be injected from `forest`' by using `forest`'s `tikz` option (again, at any node, but probably in the preamble).

In your example, use this definition of `tag` style (the first way is active, the second way is commented out):

```
\forestset{tag/.style={
    for tree={parent anchor=south, child anchor=north,align=center,base=top},where n children=0{}{},
    begin draw/.code={\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]},
    %tikz+={\pgfsetbaselinepointlater{\pgfpointanchor{current bounding box}{center}}},
  }}
```

Answer (score 4):

Seek help from `adjustbox` package with `valign=m or c` (t for top, b for bottom) does the objectives.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{minimal}   
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{forest}

\forestset{
tag/.style={for tree={parent anchor=south, child anchor=north, align=center, base=top}, where  n children=0{}{}}
}


\begin{document}


\hfill
\adjustbox{valign=c}{
\begin{forest}
tag
[NP
        [John]]
\end{forest}}
\hfill
\adjustbox{valign=c}{
\begin{forest}
tag
[S
        [NP$\downarrow$]
        [VP
                [V
                        [laughs]]]]
\end{forest}}
\hfill
\adjustbox{valign=c}{
\begin{forest}
tag
[VP
        [ADV
                [always]]
        [VP*]]
\end{forest}}
\hfill\mbox{}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! When I load it, I get an error telling me that `\clipbox` is already defined. Hm.

Comment: The `adjustbox` package does use `clipbox` according to its manual located in the INTRODUCTION. So your code must have other packages cause such clash. Probably, disable those packages first and find out which one is causing this error. Further, I checked the version of adjustbox package in the compiled log file: adjustbox 2012/05/21 v1.0

Comment: Please check this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/86032/34618.  egreg's second alternative could be one possible solution. If not, then a new question is indeed justified.

Comment: Thanks! It was `pstricks` and the link to the trick was very helpful indeed!

Comment: You are welcome, I leaned from your question too. Thanks.