# Positioning of trees

Tags: trees

Consider

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}   
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree-compat}

\begin{document}

X + Y $\Rightarrow$ \begin{tikzpicture} \Tree [.X X Y ] \end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Suppose I want X[...] and not X in the tree below. How can I insert it? How can I get X and Y to have <...> inserted just below them, in the way it has been done with A and B in p. 14-16 of these slides: http://www.ucl.ac.uk/~ucjtmgg/docs/cam-slides.pdf

How can I regulate the position of the tree? I would like to have the tree so that `X + Y $\Rightarrow$` comes roughly in the middle of where the tree is, as in page 17 of the slides above:

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: Mostly duplicate of [tikz pgf - An arrow between two tikzpictures - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/260587/an-arrow-between-two-tikzpictures?noredirect=1&lq=1) -- except in this case `forest` can be used as well.

Answer (score 2):

The vertical placement of the figure can be done in many different ways.
There is option `baseline`. Setting it to the center of the image `(current bounding box.center)` puts the middle on the current baseline of the surrounding text. The third example will show a way to center the image around the current math axis.

The second image puts the leafs on the same base line as the surrounding text.

The third image uses macro `\VCenter` to center the image around the math axis. The text before looks more like an equation. The centering is done via the TeX primitive `\vcenter`.

Additionally the nodes contain the angle brackets in a second line.

Full example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree-compat}

\newcommand*{\VCenter}[1]{%
  \ensuremath{%
    \vcenter{%
      \hbox{#1}%
    }%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

X + Y $\Rightarrow$
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
  \Tree [.X X Y ]
\end{tikzpicture}

\bigskip

\underline{X + Y $\Rightarrow$
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(X.base)]
  \Tree [.X \node(X){X}; Y ]
\end{tikzpicture}}

\bigskip

X + Y $\Rightarrow$
\VCenter{\begin{tikzpicture}[
  every node/.append style={align=center},
  level distance=50pt,
]
  \Tree [ .\node{X\\$\langle\ldots\rangle$};
    \node{X\\$\langle\alpha\rangle$};
    \node{Y\\$\langle\beta\rangle$};
  ]
\end{tikzpicture}}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}   
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree-compat}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\raisebox{3\baselineskip}{X + Y $\Rightarrow$} 
\tikzset{level 1/.style={level distance=60pt,sibling distance=30pt}}
\begin{tikzpicture} \Tree [.\stackunder{X}{$\langle$...$\rangle$} 
\stackunder{X}{$\langle\alpha\rangle$} \stackunder{Y}{$\langle\beta\rangle$} ] 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A compact `forest` solution which uses `baseline` to set an empty node to the baseline of the tree.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
  X + Y $\Rightarrow$
  \begin{forest}
    for tree={align=center, parent anchor=south, child anchor=north, if n children=0{tier=t}{}}
    [{X\\$[\dots]$} [{X\\$\langle\alpha\rangle$}] [, no edge, baseline [, phantom]] [{Y\\$\langle\beta\rangle$}] ]
  \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: baseline forest]

Comment: I think using phantom node is not very reliable though. Could use [adjustbox with valign=m](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/206728/aligning-several-forest-trees-in-centered-way/206731#206731) instead.