# Children misalignment in forest

Tags: vertical-alignment, line-breaking, tikz-trees, forest, typewriter

**Problem**

I am trying to draw a tree diagram with `forest` package. I have multiline children including the `\texttt` command and a one-line child with normal text. This results in a misalignment among the children, as you can see from the picture below.

[image]

I would like all children to be top-aligned. How can I achieve that?

MWE:

```
% Class
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

% Forest package
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

%Defining the styles used in trees
\tikzset{standard/.style={align=center,text width=3cm,rounded corners=2pt},
    wide/.style={align=center,text width=4.2cm,rounded corners=2pt},
    narrow/.style={align=center,text width=2cm,rounded corners=2pt}
}

% Document
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[hbt!]
        \centering
        \begin{forest}
            for tree={%
                %               grow'=0,
                l sep=0.5cm,
                s sep=0.1cm,
                minimum height=0.8cm,
                minimum width=2cm,
                draw%
            },
            forked edges,
            [\texttt{Parent} object, standard
                [\texttt{AStandardChild} object, standard]
                [\texttt{VeryVeryVeryLongChild} object, wide]
                [Other, narrow]
            ]
        \end{forest}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

**Attempted solution**

I tried to use some additional `for tree` options inspired by [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/206728/aligning-several-forest-trees-in-centered-way). In this attempt I need to force the line break (`\\`) of the long tree elements because that would not happen automatically. The misalignment is reduced but it is still present.

[image]

MWE:

```
% Class
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

% Forest package
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

%Defining the styles used in trees
\tikzset{standard/.style={align=center,text width=3cm,rounded corners=2pt},
    wide/.style={align=center,text width=4.2cm,rounded corners=2pt},
    narrow/.style={align=center,text width=2cm,rounded corners=2pt}
}

% Document
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[hbt!]
        \centering
        \begin{forest}
            for tree={%
                %               grow'=0,
                l sep=0.5cm,
                s sep=0.1cm,
                minimum height=0.8cm,
                minimum width=2cm,
                parent anchor=south, child anchor=north, align=center, base=top,
                draw%
            },
            forked edges,
            [\texttt{Parent} object, standard
                [\texttt{AStandardChild}\\object, standard]
                [\texttt{VeryVeryVeryLongChild}\\object, wide]
                [Other, narrow]
            ]
        \end{forest}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

You only need to add (in your simple example)  `anchor=north` to styles of nodes:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

% Document
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[hbt!]
        \centering
        \begin{forest}
    for tree={              % style of tree nodes
      draw, semithick, rounded corners,
      align = center,
      inner sep = 2mm,
      anchor=north,
                            % styles of tree
      forked edge,             
%      tier/.option=level,  % if you have more levels of children
        l sep = 6mm,    
     fork sep = 3mm,     
                }
[\texttt{Parent}\\   object
    [\texttt{AStandardChild}\\ object]
    [\texttt{VeryVeryVeryLongChild}\\ object]
    [\textrm{Other}]
]
        \end{forest}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```